# How to change full ios app font programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uilabel, objective-c-category

In my app I giving user an option to change font of the whole app. To do so I am giving user a list of options(like bold, semibold, regular, thin etc). As soon as user selects any of the above options I am saving that value in the NSUserDefaults.

Now as user has selected his option so I should change my whole app's font. For the same I created a category

```
#import "UILabel+Helper.h"

@implementation UILabel (Helper)

- (void)setSubstituteFontName:(NSString *)name UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR {

if ([name  isEqual: kAppFontSFTextBold]) {
    self.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
}
else if ([name  isEqual:kAppFontSFTextSemiBold]) {
    self.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline];
}
else if ([name  isEqual: kAppFontSFTextMedium]) {
    self.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
}
else if ([name  isEqual: kAppFontSFTextRegular]) {
    self.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption1];
}
else if ([name  isEqual: kAppFontSFTextLight]) {
    self.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption2];
}

//    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:name size:self.font.pointSize];
}

@end
```

But to make these change in my app I have to restart my app programmatically and apple doesn't support that. After reading few answers I came to know that I can forcefully terminate my app using exit(0).

Now as soon as user selects the option I am saving selected value in local as said earlier and exit(0). Now user has to restart the app on its own.

Is this approach correct or not. If not then please suggest me with a better solution.

Comment: exit(0) will lead to the rejection of your app from Apple

Answer (score 1):

Register below notification on each VC to the end of viewDidLoad: . It will be good to add it in base class of all VC Or VC categories.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                          addObserver:self
                             selector:@selector(preferredContentSizeChanged:)
                                 name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification
                               object:nil];
```

And then in selector method update your font with below method :

```
 - (void)preferredContentSizeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
     self.textView.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
}
```

For more detail see [Core Text](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following things. You see you can simply fire a `NSNotification` when the user selects the font. You can add an observer in every `UIViewController` where there are `UILabel`s. Then, you can simply change those `UILabel` font in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Using following code you code achieve your goal .

```
1. -(void)setFonts{
        NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"langkey"]; ;
        UIFont *font ;
        if ([name  isEqual: kAppFontSFTextBold]) {
            font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
        }
        else if ([name  isEqual:kAppFontSFTextSemiBold]) {
            font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline];
        }
        else if ([name  isEqual: kAppFontSFTextMedium]) {
            font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
        }
        else if ([name  isEqual: kAppFontSFTextRegular]) {
            font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption1];
        }
        else if ([name  isEqual: kAppFontSFTextLight]) {
            font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption2];
        }

        [[UILabel appearance] setFont:font];

        [[UITextField appearance] setFont:font];

        [[UITextView appearance] setFont:font];
    }
```

this method you can write in appdelegate and call using create  appdelegate's instance .

this is user defined method so you need to call while your user selection occur.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Hope this helps :

    AnyUIView.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "yourFont", size: yourSize)

//code this inside AppDelegate in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method. and also , Be sure to add your chosen font to your projects target if you're using a custom font.
```